# Is there a way to detect whether or not a click event occurred within a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog

Is there a way to detect whether or not a user clicked on a link from within a jQuery dialog?

The dialog is opened using `moreBlock.dialog('open');` and the link is available from the parent window and within the jQuery dialog.

I need to detect whether the link was clicked from within an open dialog or just from the parent window.

Thanks!

Comment: May be you can just add a class `clicked` in the link after the click occured and check this before each click action.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you attach a different class to the jQuery dialogue box link, so that when the event is triggered, you can read it from the element that raised it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just check to see if it's inside the dialog by checking if it has a parent with a `ui-dialog` class

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if($(this).closest('.ui-dialog').length > 0){
        // code here for anchor inside dialog
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5V68/1/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to intercept the click event and display `this.id` or some other unique identifying attribute.